# How to retrieve a value from jquery in C# user control?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, user-controls

I have a visitorID variable in ToDo function in external javascript.

I want to assign its' value in a user control. Front End Code:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidVisitorID" runat="server" Value="-1"/>

<script type="text/javascript">

$j('#<%= hidVisitorID.ClientID %>').val(ToDo.visitorID);

</script>
```

In the back end it says, that hidVisitorID.Value is null (or -1 in this case). How do I assign value from jquery variable to hidVisitorID ?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about what you are actually trying to accomplish by doing this?  In the present case, it might be sufficient just to have a normal HTML hidden input, but I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the ASP.NET control.

Comment: I think you are confusing the front end with the back end... but I can't tell for sure from your question.

Comment: sorry, will update a question now

Comment: Where does ToDo.visitorID come from? and are you sure there are no other JavaScript errors?

Comment: @Andrew I need a value, which only exists in ToDo javascript be assigned to a variable in a user control.

Comment: Todo.visitorID comes from ToDo.js (jquery variable). No errors in that file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="my_TO_DO.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('my todo varname is: ' + ToDo.variableName);
        $('#<%= hidVisitorID.ClientID %>').val("foobar");
    });
</script>


 <asp:HiddenField ID="hidVisitorID" runat="server" Value="-1"/>

 <asp:Button Text="sub" runat="server" onclick="Click" />
```

When you click the button, it'll post back.

```
protected void Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string valFromHidden = hidVisitorID.Value;
   //valFromHidden is now foobar
}
```

Ensure your jQuery reference is ABOVE your other .js reference.

Comment: this will work. But I cant get my variable from ToDo.js to work instead of "foobar". I put .val(ToDo.variableName) and it doesnt recognize ToDo

Comment: @Display: check out the update on the answer here. `Alert()` and placing of the various .js script tags.

Comment: I have a feeling, that I should refactor my javascript to make it work.. as some values are assigned loading events later on. Anyway, thanks for your answer.